# Node.js Calling functions as quickly as possible without going over some limit

Tags: node.js, api, throttling, rate-limiting

I have multiple functions that call different api endpoints, and I need to call them as quickly as possible without going over some limit (20 calls per second for example). My current solution is to have a delay and call the function once every 50 milliseconds for the example I gave, but I would like to call them as quickly as possible and not just space out the calls equally with the rate limit.

Comment: See the "leaky bucket" algorithm and associated NPM packages that help you use it.

Comment: you need throttling or debouncing

Answer (score 0):

[function-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-rate-limit) solved a similar problem for me. function-rate-limit spreads out calls to your function over time, without dropping calls to your function. It still allows instantaneous calls to you function until the rate limit is reached, so it can behave with no latency introduced under normal circumstances.

Example from function-rate-limit docs:

```
var rateLimit = require('function-rate-limit');

// limit to 2 executions per 1000ms 
var start = Date.now()
var fn = rateLimit(2, 1000, function (x) {
  console.log('%s ms - %s', Date.now() - start, x);
});

for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  fn(y);
}
```

results in:

```
10 ms - 0
11 ms - 1
1004 ms - 2
1012 ms - 3
2008 ms - 4
2013 ms - 5
3010 ms - 6
3014 ms - 7
4017 ms - 8
4017 ms - 9
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using queue from [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue). Be careful when doing this, it essentially behaves like a `while(true)` in other languages:

```
const async = require('async');

const concurrent = 10; // At most 10 concurrent ops;
const tasks = Array(concurrent).fill().map((e, i) => i);

let pushBack; // let's create a ref to a lambda function

const myAsyncFunction = (task) => {
  // TODO: Swap with the actual implementation
  return Promise.resolve(task);
};

const q = async.queue((task, cb) => {
  myAsyncFunction(task)
    .then((result) => {
      pushBack(task);
      cb(null, result);
    })
    .catch((err) => cb(err, null));
}, tasks.length);

pushBack = (task) => q.push(task);
q.push(tasks);
```

What's happening here? We are saying "hey run X tasks in parallel" and after each task gets completed, we put it back in the queue which is the equivalent of saying "run X tasks in parallel forever"